# I copied a workspace and now catkin_make doesn't work

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a workspace `catkin_ws_01` and created some packages inside it.

Then I duplicated that same workspace folder to create `catkin_ws_02` and made some changes to the packages inside. Then I deleted the original workspace folder `catkin_ws_01`.

Now when I try to run `catkin_make` from inside `catkin_ws_02`, it gives me the following error message:

`CMake Error: The source directory "/home/blabla/catkin_ws_01/src" does not exist.`

This means that `catkin_make` still refers to `catkin_ws_01` even though I am executing the command from within `catkin_ws_02`.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276269/i-copied-a-workspace-and-now-catkin_make-doesn%27t-work/) by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-11-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2017-11-19**:
Have you copied the compiled folders (build and devel)?
I would remove these folders and try to compile again

I don't think the compilation problem is related to that, but it's also important to check your .bashrc file and remove any sourcing command of your old catkin_ws_01 workspace.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-19**:
@alexe please don't delete questions after they've been answered.

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2017-11-19**:
@ahendrix I'm sorry, when I deleted the question I didn't even realize that there had already been an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Indigo distribution, I have tried to do the same in my computer and I got the following error:

```
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/marcoarruda/catkin_02/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/marcoarruda/catkin_01/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
```

Then, I have removed the folders `build` and `devel` from `catkin_02` and tried to compile again. It worked!

I don't think the compilation problem is related to that, but it's also important to remove any `source catkin_01/devel/setup.bash` instruction (maybe you have added to your `.bashrc` file)

I've created a video showing the steps to reproduce and solve it (https://youtu.be/Lg_oM4vFIEs).

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2017-11-19**:
Thanks, the `build` and `devel` folders were exactly the issue! After deleting them, building worked as expected :)